# datetime.strptime: TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to strip my date but it gives following error:

```
df1["Date"] = datetime.datetime.strptime(df1["Date"][:10], "%Y-%m-%d")
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

This is my code:

```
df1["Date"] = datetime.datetime.strptime(df1["Date"][:10], "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Are you using pandas? Can you `print(df1["Date"][:10])`?

Comment: You need to use `pd.to_datetime`.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear, are you going from datetime to string or string to datetime?

Answer (score 0):

Try to go from String to Date:

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Or do you need the other way from Date to String

```
df1['Date'] = df1['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```